# Excel - Index/Match to Parse Column Data Until Desired Value Shows

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I'm not sure the best way to word this question, but basically I have a big list of different names and IDs that will be visited multiple times with data pulled from a Survey123 form. One of the fields is asking if a part has been repaired, which will be no a maximum of 3 times before turning yes.

I'm using Index/Match to keep track of the dates the visits took place, but if I try it for the repair column it will always just return the first value in the repair column. Is there a way I can have it parse all the repair column values and change the result if it is Yes?

Here is a visual of what I'm trying to achieve, using Index/Match will stop at the first result rather than cycling through.

[image]

Comment: What result do you want if there no `YES` for a particular ID? Can you few more data with different variation?

Comment: What is your excel version? Do you have ***Excel-365***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below formula. If any of visit has `Yes` in repaired column then it will return `Yes` or will return `No`.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A3:A5=F3)*(B3:B5=G3)*(D3:D5="Yes"))>0,"Yes","No")
```

Or you can use `XLOOKUP()` with `Search_Mode` option `-1` means ***search last to first*** order.

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(A3:A5=F3)*(B3:B5=G3),D3:D5,"",0,-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FILTER` to achieve this

```
=FILTER(C2:C4,(A2:A4=F4)*(B2:B4=G4)*(C2:C4="Yes"),"No")
```

[image]